# After Service Principal creation with graph, how to know when will it be available for role definition with ARM?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-resource-manager

I am currently following this script to make the direct API calls to graph and to ARM to programatically create an Active Directory Application, a Service Principal referencing that created App, and a role assignment to that created service principal.

It works well since I must only use JavaScript: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/Documentation/ServicePrincipal/spCreate.js

The problem is that trying to assign the role in the success callback of the service principal creation, at line 134, results in a 400 Error, stating that the service principal was not found. This issue occurs when trying to make the request immediately on the success callback, if I wait for about 20 seconds after the success callback of the service principal creation then the role assignment works.

So my question is, what would be the best way to deal with the role assignment without the need of setting a sleep/setTimeOut to wait for the changes to propagate in Azure? Is there some other webhook/event or something that signals that the service principal is available?

Comment: May be helpful...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-async-operations

You can check whether your API response-header has 'Location' OR 'Azure-AsyncOperation' and Retry-After headers.

If so, you can wait till X seconds (generally it's 17 seconds, based Retry-After header), then you can try your next call.

Comment: I would recommend a retry loop with several retries - in the case of `azure-credentials`, a Ruby gem that automates service principal creation, I had to increase the number of retries from 5 to 100, with 2 sec delay between tries - [code link](https://github.com/pendrica/azure-credentials/blob/master/lib/azure/utility/credentials.rb#L237).  Probably something between 5 and 100 is required, but I think it will vary depending on local Azure workload and capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such webhook/event for this scenario. As a workaround, you may check the result of role assignment, if it was failed, you can send the request repeatedly.

In addition, if you have any idea or feedback about Azure Active Directory, you can submit them from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).